# P/Invoke during PSSession

Tags: powershell, pinvoke

For some reason, P/Invoke via PSSession is not working.  I have a client side script which I run from a server through a PSSession.  Here's the code for the client-side script:

```
$signature = @"
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern bool BlockInput(bool fBlockIt);
"@

$block = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name DisableInput -Namespace DisableInput -PassThru
$unblock = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name EnableInput -Namespace EnableInput -PassThru

$block::BlockInput($true)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$unblock::BlockInput($false)
```

I'm basically testing blocking/unblocking keyboard and mouse access, based off a walkthrough I found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.powershell.nu/2012/10/08/block-and-unblock-keyboard-mouse-input-using-powershell/&ei=KvyfUp3XIZHsoATFvoDIBw&usg=AFQjCNGB7APD7y-Cro0DCJK-HoKFUpTvgQ&bvm=bv.57155469,d.cGU).  I can successfully get the script to run, and the account I'm running it with should have elevated permissions, but for some reason, the call to `$block::BlockInput` and `$unblock::BlockInput` are both returning `False`, and neither the keyboard nor the mouse are blocked.

When I run the exact same script with the same account directly on the client machine, the script does exactly what it should - locks the keyboard and mouse for 10 seconds, and both calls to `BlockInput` return `True`.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it possible to P/Invoke via a PSSession?

Comment: Have you eliminated any possible permission issues as the cause? I've always faced some difficulty with running Powershell scripts on remote machine; although I admit I've never used PSSession.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My explanation : As far as I understand when you run a remote script in a PSSession it executes in a workspace totaly separate from the user one. For example if you start notepad, you can see that the notepad is executed on the remote computer but you can't see it on the UI. Your script block the console keyboard of the PSSession workspace, but not the one of the user.

---

More explanation :

The diagrams below show the relationships between sessions, windows stations, desktops and services in Windows Vista and newest versions.  Begining in Windows Vista Session 0 is the base session where services run, the console session is typically Session 1.

[image]

When you use as PSSession a remote process is created WSMPROVHST.EXE. As you can see in the following capture, this process run in session 0, and your user interact with session 1.

[image]

In [Sessions, Desktops and Windows Stations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx) blog you will find the whole explanation.

Comment: @Brian Gradin, I link to more acurate explanation.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for your detailed explanation, and for the link!  Can you think of any way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish?  For instance, before posting, I thought this might be the case, so I tried passing the client-side script as a command-line parameter to powershell.exe on the client machine.  Same result.  Can you think of any workarounds?

Comment: @Brian Gradin I would try [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). But it should be the same thing. I just do not try it. I even don't know if on the theorical point of view it's possible to start a process in another session using PInvoke, but I'am interested in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code:**

**Code Starts here**

```
$signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool BlockInput(bool fBlockIt);
"@
$BlockInput = Add-Type -memberDefinition $signature -name Win32BlockInput -namespace     Win32Functions -passThru

function Enable-BlockInput { $null = $BlockInput::BlockInput($true) }
function Disable-BlockInput{ $null = $BlockInput::BlockInput($false)}
```

**Until this part is definition part which you can defined in a seperate .PS1 file or before the following code.**

**Below is command to block input**

```
Enable-BlockInput
```

**Below is the command to Release input**

```
Disable-BlockInput
```

It worked for me ...hope will work for you as well,Good luck

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Try to explain your code a bit more though.